# Move WordPress posts and related taxonomy to custom post type & taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a clean WordPress installation using Twenty Eleven, with no plugins or other modifications. The blog contains approximately 800 posts with related tags and categories.

I'd like to move all these posts to a custom post type. By adding the following code to my functions.php my blog now has the custom post type installed and working perfectly.

```
//Add custom post type
add_action( 'init', 'create_en_post_type' );
    function create_en_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'en_post',  array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'English Posts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'English Post' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'en'),
            'supports' => array(
                'title', 
                'editor', 
                'author', 
                'excerpt', 
                'comments', 
                'custom-fields'
            )
        ));
    }

//Add belonging custom taxonomy
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 ); 
    function build_taxonomies() { 
    register_taxonomy( 'english_categories', 'en_post', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'English Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    register_taxonomy( 'english_tags', 'en_post', array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'English Tags', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    }
```

Now all I need is to change the regular post type to my custom post type. I've managed to move the posts using the plugin [Convert Post Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/), but my taxonomies aren't converted.

I realize I could just create similar custom categories and assign the custom posts to them, but what about tags? How can I convert these (automatically, 1200 tags)?

I've tried manually messing around in the database, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the ID's in the database, take a long look at the phpmyadmin

- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_terms
- wp_term_relationships

In the terms table you will find the id of the old and new taxamonies
in term_taxonomy replace all old `term_id` with the new.

SQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_term_relationships` SET `term_id` = REPLACE(`term_id`, /*old id*/, /*new id*/);
```

Do make a **backup** before you start

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I don't think I made myself clear though. I don't have any "new id" because the tags only reside at one place (they are standard tags). In my mind I thought I could just change the post_tag in the taxonomy column to custom_post_tag (wp_term_taxonomy table). After this the tags are surely listed as custom taxonomies, but they are not connected to their custom posts. I now need to link them using the IDs you are talking about! Right? Maybe my problem is more clear to you now? Thanks.

Comment: you could enable the default(standard post posttype) tags on the custom post. then 'post' and 'English posts' would share the same tags. I know not what you are asking.
But I'm not sure what you're asking..

Comment: I want to convert every post, tag & category to custom, so I can have two separate blogs in my WordPress install.

Comment: That's what I thought. Then my solution will work, just switch all the taxonomies ID's