# Move taxonomies to a new post type

Tags: wordpress

I have a strange situation where I need to move current taxonomies from one post type to a new one in Wordpress.

If I change the taxonomy post type within the functions I am losing all categories and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the ID's in the database, take a long look at the phpmyadmin

- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_terms
- wp_term_relationships

In the terms table you will find the id of the old and new taxamonies
in term_taxonomy replace all old term_id with the new.

SQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_term_relationships` SET `term_id` = REPLACE(`term_id`, /*old id*/, /*new id*/);
```

Do make a backup before you start.
Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234176/move-wordpress-posts-and-related-taxonomy-to-custom-post-type-taxonomy)

Comment: Thanks @uvishere will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

While @uvishere is right with his answer when you have a lot of categories to deal with that process can be a real headache.

What I have done is I created the taxonomies keeping their previous names under the new post types. Wordpress however will not add the new categories to these new post types once I uploaded the code but I then removed the old taxonomies from the code and all categories shifted under the new post type keeping the id's relationships ecc.. which was great and fast!

Now all I had to do is move the posts from one post type to the other and I have done so using the Post Type Switcher plugin